# Why does apollo muation return "Expecting a parsed GraphQL document" inside vuex?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I am trying to execute an apollo mutation from vuex actions. But it always returns this error :

```
Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag? http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html#gql
```

This is how I imported the GraphQL file:

```
import addReservationGql from "@/gql/mutation/addReservation.gql";
```

Here is the GeaphQL mutation file:

```
mutation addReservation($reservation:ResrevationInput){
  addReservation(reservation:$reservation){
    code
    success
    message
    reservation{
      createdAt
      numberOfPeople
      desiredDate
      desiredTime
      reservationStatus
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my mutation call inside vuex actions:

async submitReservation({ state, commit }) {

```
    const userId = this.$cookies.get("user-id");
    const reservation = {
        numberOfPeople: state.numberOfPeople,
        desiredDate: state.reservationDate,
        desiredTime: state.reservationTime,
        reservedBy: userId
    };

    try {
        let client = this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
        const response = await client.mutate({
            mutation: addReservationGql,
            variables: { reservation }
        });
        // do something with response


    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error',err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the `addReservation.gql` file.

Comment: @Eldar I have added the contents

Comment: Do you have any webpack configuration about loading a `gql` file?

Comment: @Eldar No. I am using the default webpack config of nuxtjs.

Answer (score 0):

By default webpack has no configuration for `gql` or `graphql` files. You need to add the configuration explicitly.

install required package.

> `npm i graphql-tag --save`

Then configure webpack.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: When I tried to extend webpack config like you said, it generates the error "GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "var""

Comment: @Elder, I have another apollo query inside the vuex actions, it works fine without any custom webpack configuration. But the problem is with the mutation.